# Parse multilingual json file into C# dictionary

Tags: c#, json

How do I read into a C# dictionary, a multilingual json lexicon in the form:

```
[{
  "Top": {
    "de-DE": "Oben",
    "fr-FR": "haut"
  }
},    {
  "Football": {
    "de-DE": "Fußball",
  },
},
{
  "Taxi": {
  }
}]
```

In the json file there is a key, and for each supported language, a property and value. Where the word in the target language is the same as the key, there is no property for that language under that key in the json file.

At startup we load into a C# dictionary only those entries for the user language. In this snippet, the dictionary for German should be

```
Top, Oben
Football, Fußball
Taxi, Taxi
```

In French

```
Top, Haut
Football, Football,
Taxi, Taxi
```

How do I read the json file into a C# dictionary? The dictionary is not huge ... hundreds rather than millions of entries, so performance is not critical.

Comment: You go to http://QuickType.io , paste a sample of Json in and hit the button that generates C# :) (they also have a vs extension that allows you to paste Json into VS and it appears as c# code)

Comment: The JSON you posted is not valid JSON. Did you miss the square brackets?

Comment: If you can change the structure, you could use a slightly different (and IMHO much better) structure [in this example on .net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aonyoc)

Comment: @SirRufo I'm not sure how your example would work as we support multiple languages, so although where there is no entry for de-DE there might be an entry for fr-FR and other languages. A missing property for one language does not allow us to set the element to null. Perhaps I've misunderstood?

Comment: I've updated my question to show a more complete example

Comment: @Vague I have updated [my sample too](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9AFXO7)

Comment: @Vague Your JSON is still **NOT** valid - there is no way to answer your question if you post data that will not work in any way

Comment: @SirRufo I've added square brackets (it is only a snippet) do you mean invalid because some elements will not have properties?

Comment: @Vague Without the square brackets the Json is invalid, and we/I cannot answer on questions with invalid data - except: your data is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed your JSON is List of Array

```
[
  {
    "Top": {
      "de-DE": "Oben",
      "fr-FR": "haut"
    }
  },
  {
    "Football": {
      "de-DE": "Fußball"
    }
  },
  {
    "Taxi": {
    }
  }
]
```

You can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to convert the json to `Dictionary`

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(json);

//DE Dictionary
var deDict = results.SelectMany(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => JObject.Parse(x.Value.ToString())["de-DE"] == null ? "" : JObject.Parse(x.Value.ToString())["de-DE"].ToString());

//FR Dictionary
var frDict = results.SelectMany(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => JObject.Parse(x.Value.ToString())["fr-FR"] == null ? "" : JObject.Parse(x.Value.ToString())["fr-FR"].ToString());

//DE Dictionary     
foreach (var keyvalue in deDict)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{keyvalue.Key} : {keyvalue.Value}");
}

//FR Dictionary
foreach (var keyvalue in frDict)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{keyvalue.Key} : {keyvalue.Value}");
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Top : Oben
Football : Fußball
Taxi :

Top : haut
Football :
Taxi :
```

Comment: The output in this case is not a dictionary:key-value pairs

Comment: @Vague, I have updated the post to push the results to `Dictionary`

Comment: @Vague, does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

The types

```
public class LocalizationInfo : Dictionary<string, string>
{
    public LocalizationInfo() : base( StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase ) { }
}

public class LocalizationItem : Dictionary<string, LocalizationInfo>
{ }

public class LocalizationCollection : List<LocalizationItem>
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> GetLocalizedDict( string cultureName )
    {
        if ( cultureName is null )
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( cultureName ) );
        }

        return this
            .Where( e => e.Count == 1 )
            .Select( e => e.First() )
            .ToDictionary( e => e.Key, e => e.Value == null ? e.Key : e.Value.TryGetValue( cultureName, out var localizedValue ) ? localizedValue : e.Key );
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> GetLocalizedDict( CultureInfo cultureInfo )
    {
        if ( cultureInfo is null )
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( cultureInfo ) );
        }

        return GetLocalizedDict(cultureInfo.Name);
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> GetLocalizedDict(  )
    {
        return GetLocalizedDict( CultureInfo.CurrentCulture );
    }
}
```

and the use case

```
class Program
{
    static readonly string _json =
        "[{" + Environment.NewLine +
        "  \"Top\": {" + Environment.NewLine +
        "    \"de-DE\": \"Oben\"," + Environment.NewLine +
        "    \"fr-FR\": \"haut\"" + Environment.NewLine +
        "  }" + Environment.NewLine +
        "},    {" + Environment.NewLine +
        "  \"Football\": {" + Environment.NewLine +
        "    \"de-DE\": \"Fußball\"" + Environment.NewLine +
        "  }" + Environment.NewLine +
        "}," + Environment.NewLine +
        "{" + Environment.NewLine +
        "  \"Taxi\": {" + Environment.NewLine +
        "  }" + Environment.NewLine +
        "}]";

    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<LocalizationCollection>( _json );

        var frDict = data.GetLocalizedDict( "fr-fr" );
        var deDict = data.GetLocalizedDict( "de-de" );

        var dict = data.GetLocalizedDict();
    }
}
```

and [a live example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QXsZed)

### BTW

I had choosen a structure like this

```
{
  "Top": {
    "de-DE": "Oben",
    "fr-FR": "haut"
  },
  "Football": {
    "de-DE": "Fußball"
  },
  "Taxi": {}
}
```

There is no need for an array with objects which only contain a single property.